# Getting issue in running NGINX

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I have an AWS Lightsail instance and running NGINX and apache on different ports. (Apache on 8080 and Nginx on 80). It was running fine but from the morning the Nginx has stopped working and on restarting it is giving this below issue. And any of my websites are not loading

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-08-26 09:09:59 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 9892 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9908 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9906 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9894 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9907 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 2348)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─9907 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─9909 nginx: worker process

Aug 26 09:09:59 ip-172-26-3-19 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 26 09:09:59 ip-172-26-3-19 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

This is the nginx error log

```
2020/08/26 06:17:09 [alert] 1930#1930: *20 open socket #18 left in connection 9
2020/08/26 06:17:09 [alert] 1930#1930: *35 open socket #17 left in connection 14
2020/08/26 06:17:09 [alert] 1930#1930: aborting
```

I have tried nginx -t. Which is also successfull.

Please help with this

Comment: Could you provide the output of nginx -V and some debug logs?

Comment: output of nginx -v ```nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)```.

Comment: which debug logs are you talking about ? @Tolsadus

Comment: Do you have any use full logs in /var/log/nginx/error.log or journalctl -u nginx ? You need to provide more information. The error you are seeing with systemd is generic.

Comment: Have you tried properly shutting down nginx service? Run `systemctl stop nginx`. You can further verify if any nginx processes are still running with `ps aux|grep nginx`. I suspect it's not properly shutdown, causing issues with the port.

Comment: @sykez It shows me this after stopping nginx 
```ubuntu   30930  0.0  0.0  14848  1032 pts/0    S+   12:37   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx```

Comment: When I restart php-fpm it starts working again, So, I think it is having some issue with php-fpm